# Experience Editor - "" is not a valid number

Tags: experience-editor, validation

I am currently facing an error with the Experience Editor and integer field.

So I have a Datasource template that has a field of integer type (without validation - meaning not required). Through the Experience Editor I create a new Datasource Item based on this template.

Rendering and data show as expected and, by default, this field is empty - which again is fine.

However if I save the page I get the following error:

[image: error message]

I do understand that it is because of the field being empty and therefore string empty is not a number, but this field can be empty.

If I put a number in, saving works as expected.

This happens with Sitecore 8.0 (rev. 150427)

Comment: I thought that I'd come across this problem with the XHTML validation triggering for the Rich Text fields however I couldn't see the same settings for the integer field. I'm wondering if it's just built in field validation for these low level field types. You could try creating a new NullableInteger field?